# Format text with regard to punctuation

Tags: text, formatting, diff, nlp

How can I format text in a natural language taking punctuation into account?  The built-in `gq` command of Vim, or command line tools, such as [fmt](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?fmt) or [par](http://www.nicemice.net/par/) break lines without regard to punctuation.  Let me give you an example,

`fmt -w 40` gives not what I want:

```
we had everything before us, we had
nothing before us, we were all going
direct to Heaven, we were all going
direct the other way
```

`smart_formatter -w 40` would give:

```
we had everything before us,
we had nothing before us,
we were all going direct to Heaven,
we were all going direct the other way
```

Of course, there are cases when no punctuation mark is found within the given text width, then it can fallback to the standard text formatting behavior.

The reason why I want this is to get a meaningful `diff` of text where I can spot which sentence or subsentence changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a not very elegant, but working method I finally came up with.  Suppose, a line break at a punctuation mark is worth 6 characters.  It means, I'll accept a result which is more ragged but contains more lines ending in a punctuation mark if the "raggedness" is less than 6 characters long.  For example, this is OK ("raggedness" is 3 characters).

```
Wait!
He said.
```

This is not OK ("raggedness" is more than 6 characters)

```
Wait!
He said to them.
```

The method is to add 6 dummy characters after each punctuation mark, format the text, then remove the dummy characters.

Here is the code for this

```
sed -e 's/\([.?!,]\)/\1 _ _ _/g' | fmt -w 34 | sed -e 's/ _//g' -e 's/_ //g'
```

I used `_` (space + underscore) as a pair of dummy characters, supposing they're not contained in the text.  The result looks quite good,

```
we had everything before us,
we had nothing before us,
we were all going direct to
Heaven, we were all going
direct the other way
```